# SQL, How to subtract from previous left over amounts, CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, lag

I need help in getting to the 'Taken' and 'left' columns of this image. I have tried a CTE and lag funtion but nothing seems to work.

If I have the first four columns in a table, how can I go about computing 'Taken' and 'left' column.

Basically, the way 'Taken' and 'left' is basically for each group, we have a max limit that column 4 can be taken out from. They have to be taken out in the order of A, B, C, D

Let me know if there are questions and I will try my best to answer.

Thanks

Since people are asking for given record set.. This is how it looks like. I need to find out logic for columns 'taken' and 'left'

```
Accountno   GroupName   MaxGroup    Amount
101          A          70           0
101          B          70           50
101          C          70          0
101          D          70          20
102          A          95          30
102          B          95           0
102          C          95           5
102          D          95           10
103          A          80           40
103          B          80          15
103          C          80          10
103          D          80           5
```

[image]

Comment: can you re-post that image as text ? it is much easier to read

Comment: If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the transcription effort? **Please don't use images of data**, paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: What are the 4 column names? I see 3, excluding taken and left.

Comment: Sorry, I was working on it on the board to get a better understanding of it. Column names are Acc no, group, max, column4. These are provided. I need to come up with computations mentioned in columns 'taken' and 'left'

Comment: Can you please post the expected result as well so that it will be easy to prepare query accordingly.

Comment: The expected result is the last two columns in the image. 'Taken' and 'left' columns

Comment: I think you expected result should be `column4` which will be derived based on the logic.

Comment: ok I have posted the given record set above. I need to apply a logic to get to numbers given in the image in the last two columns

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] (especially about homework), hits googling 'stackexhange homework' & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please show some work with justification, explain about the first place you get stuck & ask a specific question about it. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes DBMS (including version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (including input) & diffable expected output. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Justify "minimal code with a problem" for required functionality by also giving code that works for a maximal part of that functionality. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples. (These are debugging basics.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using `OUTER APPLY` as below

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE(acc_no INT, [group] CHAR(1), [maxgroup] INT, amount INT)

INSERT INTO @table VALUES
(101, 'A', 70, 0),
(101, 'B', 70, 50),
(101, 'C', 70, 0),
(101, 'D', 70, 20),
(102, 'A', 95, 30),
(102, 'B', 95, 0),
(102, 'C', 95, 5),
(102, 'D', 95, 10),
(103, 'A', 80, 40),
(103, 'B', 80,15),
(103, 'C', 80, 10),
(103, 'D', 80, 5)


SELECT t.acc_no, 
    t.[group],
    t.maxgroup,
    CASE WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL ELSE t.amount END AS taken, 
    CASE WHEN t1.assigned = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (t.maxgroup - t1.assigned) END [left]
FROM @table t
OUTER APPLY(SELECT SUM([amount]) AS assigned 
            FROM @table t1 WHERE t1.acc_no = t.acc_no AND t1.[group] <= t.[group]) t1
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    acc_no  group   maxgroup    taken   left
    101     A       70          NULL    NULL
    101     B       70          50      20
    101     C       70          0       20
    101     D       70          20      0
    102     A       95          30      65
    102     B       95          0       65
    102     C       95          5       60
    102     D       95          10      50
    103     A       80          40      40
    103     B       80          15      25
    103     C       80          10      15
    103     D       80          5       10
```

Comment: That worked great, I am trying to understand what happened in the outer apply join actually. Since group column is a string or varchar, how is t1.group <= t.group happening?

Comment: Actually if you can explain the logic you applied here, that would be sooo nice... Thanks a bunch, I spent a whole day trying to work on this with complicated logic, your approach seems so simple and easy.

Comment: Hi, so all this looks good, but if the table has values like these INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(104, 'A', 10, 0),
(104, 'B', 10, 37),
(104, 'C', 10, 0),
(104, 'D', 10, 0) Its placing 37 for taken, it should be 10 as 10 is the max that can be given to that group.

Comment: Got it fixed, Thank you sooo very much for getting me going on this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks you too for your effort in finding your above question's solution by yourself, actually I was quite busy so couldn't help you. Sorry for that and thank you very much for you appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

`max(MaxGroup) over (partition by Accountno)` this will get the MaxGroup value per Accountno

`sum(Amount) over (partition by Accountno order by GroupName)` this will give cummulative total `Amount`

```
-- create the sample table
DECLARE @sample AS TABLE
(
    Accountno   int,
    GroupName   char,
    MaxGroup    int,
    Amount      int
)

-- insert some sample data
INSERT INTO @sample VALUES
(101, 'A', 70,  0), 
(101, 'B', 70, 50), 
(101, 'C', 70,  0), 
(101, 'D', 70, 20),

(102, 'A', 95, 30), 
(102, 'B', 95,  0), 
(102, 'C', 95,  5), 
(102, 'D', 95, 10),

(103, 'A', 80, 40), 
(103, 'B', 80, 15), 
(103, 'C', 80, 10), 
(103, 'D', 80,  5)

-- the query
select  *, 
        [left]  = max(MaxGroup) over (partition by Accountno)
                - sum(Amount) over (partition by Accountno order by GroupName)
from    @sample s
order by Accountno, GroupName
```

Don't quite understand what is the logic for 2nd last column `taken` that you required. Looks like it is same as the `Amount` column to me

[demo](http://rextester.com/ZMPVDD65897)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this. I think I have it solved but taken column is basically the value that can be used column 3-column 4, but when column 4 is bigger than column 3, column 3 will be used.